# laracasts/utilities package cannot be configured properly in laravel 5.1

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I tried to install and configured **laracasts/utilities:2.0** using composer. It installed properly. But when it comes to the configuration part its gives an error.

I added:

```
Laracasts\Utilities\JavaScript\JavaScriptServiceProvider::class,
```

inside the providers array and

```
'JavaScript' => Laracasts\Utilities\JavaScript\JavaScriptFacade::class,
```

inside the aliases array. After that I can't even run

```
php artisan serve
```

because it gives an error :

```
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Class
> 'Laracasts\Utilities\JavaScript\JavaScriptServiceProvider' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

try regenerating the autoload files and do a clear compiled.

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan clear-compiled
```

Comment: I did . But It gives the same error as I run `php artisan clear-compiled`